# Вложение дерева в метрическое пространство

Tags: алгоритм, математика, графы

Как дерево в вектор каким-нибудь однозначным образом можно вложить метрическое пространство? Интересуют не сложные эмбеддинги, а просто преобразование дерева в вектор однозначно. Детерминированный алгоритм.

Comment: Код Прюфера, может быть? Или вам нужно не хранить, а использовать для каких-то вычислений? И у вас именно бинарное дерево или вы просто так тег поставили?

Comment: Уважаемые закрывающие вопросы. Пишите причину!!!

Comment: Давайте тег бинарное дерево, всё-таки, уберу. Не совесем корректно будет приводить его  к бинарному. Хотя, если вы предложите процедуру для бинарного -- это будет круто. Код Прюфера подразумевает наличие нумерации вершин. Её нужно как-то придумать. Иными словами. Хотелось бы научиться преобразовывать деревья из n вершин в вектор, для которых свойственно следующее отношение: два дерева изоморфны тогда и только тогда, когда их векторы равны. Здесь можно вводить приближённые отношения. Сейчас я выбрал qr-алгоритм и сравнение собственных чисел матрицы смежности.

Comment: Для бинарных есть нумерация Каталана.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если вы про числа каталана. То это количество деревьев. Или есть какая-то отдельная история про нумерацию? Скиньте ссылку тогда пожалуйста

Comment: @EzikBro можно это делать приближённо. Как, например, в случае, с qr-разложением. qr-разложение это обеспечивает довольно хорошо

Comment: @hedgehogues, корневое дерево соответствует правильной скобочной последовательности. Их генерируют рекурсивно. Алгоритм генерации переделывается в алгоритм поиска последовательности по её номеру. К сожалению, сперва надо выделить корень.

Comment: "Let the number so obtained be the canonical number of the tree." [lecture notes of Vikram Sharma](https://www.imsc.res.in/~vikram/DiscreteMaths/2011/tree.pdf)

Comment: [Tree isomorphism](https://www.imsc.res.in/~vikram/DiscreteMaths/2011/tree.pdf) излагает изоморфизм для корневых деревьев и для не корневых. Изоморфизм проверяется построением **канонического числа** по дереву.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое тупое - дерево - это граф, граф - это матрица инцидентности, матрицу можно развернуть в вектор.

Чтобы отображение было однозначным, матрицу нужно пересортировать (переставить строки и столбики) так, чтобы на диагонали было как можно больше единиц

Comment: Перенумеруйте вершины в матрице смежности и увас получится два вектора, которые соответсвуют одному графу. Ответ не годится

Comment: Что значит "перенумеруйте"? Что вы хотите от графа-то сохранить, топологию?

Comment: точно, хочу топологию.

Comment: слушайте, да. По поводу сортировки -- норм. Тема. Подумаю. Кажется, то, что нужно.

Comment: ну вот если мне склероз не изменяет, приведение матрицы к такому вот виду делается вполне однозначным образом

Comment: Дело  том, что эта сортировка помогает улучшить сходимость численного решения матриц, так что она во многих мат пакетах просто есть. Хотите написать сами - там применяется поиск остова в двудольном графе

Comment: да, кажется, что не обязательно даже остов делать. Попробую эту идею заюзать вместе с qr

Comment: qr будет, пакостник такой, сам переставлять строки, если у него нарисуется неугодный ноль - все завяжется на погрешности арифметики.

Comment: т.е. перед qr лучше такую процедуру проделать? Или ему индеферентно

Comment: Это уже вопрос, требующий погружения в задачу, я такими делами занимался лет 10 назад, так что увы - быстро не вспомню.
На уровне интуиции я думаю, что QR сильно завязан на линейную независимость строк матрицы, так что при достаточно плотном графе, можно получить фигню